# Wordpress - How to make plugin's short code usable in text widget

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, widget

i've written a plugin which shortcodes can easily be used in every post and page. As this plugin can be useful in a sidebar as well i want to make the text widget usable for my shortcodes.

When i googled this i found out that i can use the add_filter() function to ensure that, but this is only possible if i have access to the theme's functions.php. But as i am the creator of the plugin and not of the theme, this is not usable for me.

Does anybody know how i can make a shortcode which is introduced with a plugin usable in the widgets section?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don;t you create `widgets` as same functionality as `shortcode` ???
it also simple...Find Docs from here `http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API`..

Comment: Thanks. But what exactly do you mean. I then have to create a class first - like this: class Foo_Widget extends WP_Widget { right?

Comment: Yes...You need to create class for `widget`...
But you can try with `add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');` in your plugin's main file...
I haven't tested this is plugins.

Comment: But may be it will work from your plugin...I hope it'll work...

Answer (score 1):

Open your theme's function file.

Find a free spot after the opening php tag that isn't part of a function.

add this:

```
if (!is_admin())

{
   add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode', 11);
}
```

save the file and you should be all set.

Comment: Hello Len_D,thanks but as i said above i do not have access to the theme file as i want to make the shortcode of my plugin workable in the text widget...therefore the plugin has to perform necessary actions and not the theme.

Comment: Sorry. I totally missed that. Now I understand why you are having issues. There is apparently no way to get this functionality without modifying the template file or building the text widget functionality into your own widget.

Answer (score -1):

1. Open your page in edit mode.
2. Select your page location and line  where you want to add short code.
3. Add code here and update..