# How to display a shortcode in a new widget in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, widget, shortcode

I'm trying to add a shortcode to be displayed a reusable block in the footer section.

- I registered the new widget area, added a simple dummy test to a post.
- I took out the post's id code from the URL.
- I was told to use this to combine the reusable block shortcode with my post idea -> `[reusable_block id="116392"]` and pass it onto the new widget in a text widget.

Now the problem is that I got this displayed `[reusable_block id="116392"]` instead of the dummy text.

What have I missed?
[the new registered widget, and the shortcode in it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OL8cf.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wordpress - How to make plugin's short code usable in text widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21610569/wordpress-how-to-make-plugins-short-code-usable-in-text-widget)

Comment: Shortcodes don’t run automatically in text widgets. You need to execute the  shortcode in the page template - see the above answer.

Comment: Another question that should help: [shortcode is not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25933299/wordpress-shortcode-is-not-called)